# How to remove '\n' from end of strings while using txt files and dictionaries?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, text-files

Everything is working properly except the printing of the list, I have tried multiple ways `rstrip()`, `splitline()`, `replace()`, etc. But perhaps I am not using them correctly. I am fairly new to using dictionaries so I would appreciate some guidance for the current problem.

txt file (should already be in a list form):

```
Shopping List
ITEM 1000: Frozen Burgers
ITEM 1001: Bread
ITEM 1002: Frozen Burgers
ITEM 1003: Mayonnaise
ITEM 1004: Bread
ITEM 1005: Frozen Burgers
ITEM 1006: Mustard
ITEM 1007: Tomato
ITEM 1008: Tomato
```

Code:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_items():                                                                       
    print("""Items that repeat twice or more in the lists:
    Item Name        Repeat Times
    ------------------------------""")
    item_count = Counter()
    with open('Shopping_List.txt') as f:
        for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
            item_count.update([line[11:]])
    
    print('\r',*item_count.most_common(3),sep='\n')

def get_dictionaries(textfile):
    items = {}
    numbers = {}
    FIRST_NUM = 1000
    with open(textfile) as f:
        for lines in f.readlines()[1:]:
                numbers[FIRST_NUM]=lines.lstrip()[11:]
                items[lines.lstrip()[11:]]=items.setdefault(lines.lstrip()[11:],0)+1
                FIRST_NUM += 1
    return items,numbers

get_items()
```

Comment: question isn't clear. What seems to be the problem / expected behavior

Comment: `readlines` won't return a newline character in the strings. If there were two consecutive newlines it would return two lines, not a single line with a dangling newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the rows like this:

```
def get_items():
    print(
        """Items that repeat twice or more in the lists:
    Item Name        Repeat Times
    ------------------------------"""
    )
    item_count = Counter()
    with open("1.txt") as f:
        for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
            item_count.update([line[11:]])

    for item, count in item_count.most_common():  # <--- Here.
        print(f"{item.rstrip():>15} {count:>6}")
```

This prints the following:

```
Items that repeat twice or more in the lists:
    Item Name        Repeat Times
    ------------------------------
 Frozen Burgers      3
          Bread      2
     Mayonnaise      1
        Mustard      1
         Tomato      1
         Tomato      1
```

Answer (score 4):

The proper solution is to use a computer-readable input file format so you don't have to write your own parser.

Here's a quick refactoring to your code, though.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_items():
    print("""Items that repeat twice or more in the lists:
    Item Name        Repeat Times
    ------------------------------""")
    item_count = Counter()
    with open('Shopping_List.txt') as f:
        for idx, line in enumerate(f):
            if idx == 0:
                next
            item_count.update([line[11:].rstrip('\n')])
    for x in item_count.most_common(3):
        print('    {0:16} {1}'.format(*x))

get_items()
```

I removed the unused function. The main change is `.rstrip('\n')` though notice also how the printing and the iterating of the lines are refactored.